# Grant Limited Access permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, permissions, access

so I wanted to add someone to a Sharepoint group (sublist) so I granted them permissions but instead of adding them to the group, I mistakenly granted them directly access to the root web as View Only.

I now gave them access to the subgroup, but how can I change their permission on the root web as Limited Access again?

Thanks

Comment: You don't grant Limited Access rights. SharePoint does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just like psdpainter said, limited access is not a permission level for you to grant. It is only a bridge helps user to go through locations where he/she does not have enough permission and navigates to the specific item which he/she can access.

Quote from MS doc:

> it enables a user or group to browse to a site page or library to
> access a specific content item when they do not have permissions to
> open or edit any other items in the site or library. This level is
> automatically assigned by SharePoint when you provide access to one
> specific item. You cannot assign Limited Access permissions directly
> to a user or group yourself. Instead, when you assign, edit, or open
> permissions to the single item, SharePoint automatically assigns
> Limited Access to other required locations, such as the site or
> library in which the single item is located."

More information here:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252funderstanding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848